# How to increase the size of a Matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mosaic-plot

I made a mosaic plot with Matplotlib, but due to huge number of data points the plot is squeezed,the words overlap with each other. I want to increase the size of the plot. I tried:

```
plt.figure(figsize=())
```

It didn't work.

Here's my code:

```
from statsmodels.graphics.mosaicplot import mosaic
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(200,10)) #does not work
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 10.0
mosaic(plants_sub, ['Symbol', 'Family'], gap=0.1);
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

add this:-

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]=(enter your fig width, enter your fig height)
```

Comment: Hi, it worked. Could u plz tell me, Why are the last two bars shifted upward and how to fix it?